# Get every running query from every sesssion using Neo4j and Python

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to log every active query which has been running for more than 2 minutes. But when I use,

```
running_queries = session.run(
            "CALL dbms.listQueries()"
        )
```

I have another script running in which there is an infinite loop calling a simple query in another session. But it only returns the queries that are running inside my session.

Comment: Are you sure it's listing the query for that same session? Shouldn't it be the queries running for the same targeted database instead? If you try a long-running query against the same DB with Neo4j Browser e.g., does it end up being listed in your results in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick experiment and cannot confirm your findings. For simplicity, I used the Neo4j browser (which under the hood uses the official JavaScript driver).

First, I start a Neo4j server with APOC installed (I tried 4.4 and 5.2), I then open two tabs (`http://localhost:7474/browser/` if you started the DBMS on your local machine). In the first tab I run

```
CALL apoc.util.sleep(15000)  // sleep 15 seconds
```

in the second tab I run (within the next 15 seconds)

```
SHOW TRANSACTIONS  // CALL dbms.listQueries() has been deprecated
```

[image: show transcations result showing both queries]
and as you can see it shows both transactions. Since the queries were launched from different tabs, they were sent through different drivers. So this scenario is very similar to you having two scripts. If I had to guess why you don't see both queries, it may be because the queries you're firing off in the loop are too short. So you just miss the actual queries the moment you run `CALL dbms.listQueries()`. Notice that there is more stuff around the queries that is going on like networking and things.

Comment: Just as a quick comment: using `CALL dbms.listQueries()` (not available in 5.2, but 4.4), I also see both queries, just the result format is different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the query running in the other script. It was finishing before being caught.